# Power function fit to data set

Tags: apache-flex, math, actionscript

I have a set of data (in ArrayCollection) and I need to fit a power function { f(x)= B + x^alpha } to it, before display in LineChart.
As result I need the alpha and B paremeter.

How to do this with Flex?

Comment: Do you want (a) the maths, (b) the code, or both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to solve a [nonlinear regression](http://www.graphpad.com/curvefit/how_nonlin_works.htm).  As explained on the latter page, you can use a method of steepest descent, or the Gauss-Newton algorithm.

Here is an [online example](http://statpages.org/nonlin.html).  You can try out a fitting by entering data, and in box 4 enter the formula `a+Power(x,b)`.  The method used there is called the method of differential correction, but I believe that is the same as Gauss-Newton.  The solver is implemented in Javascript, which is closely related to ActionScript, so you might be able to follow the code there.

There is a worked example of the method on [this page](http://adorio-research.org/wordpress/?p=3024).